# Cakephp - how do you integrate any plugin with user management plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

what is the general principle of integrating plugins with user auth/management plugin,

so that the logged in users can also have access to other plugins

do you make any changes also to the databases of each plugin - or you make one common mysql  passwords database for all plugins

so that is a user has logged in - these passwords are valid for all plugins and he can see all logged-in features

Answer (score 0):

Once you installed the auth management plugin, you has admin can grant access to end users to various parts of your site.

Comment: does the auth management plugin also handle the sessions for all the other plugins once the access rights have been granted ?